# Add link to each element of json

Tags: php, json, steam

i have code that show steam inventory of player, code:

```
<?php
    function recursiveFind(array $array, $needle)
    {
        $iterator  = new RecursiveArrayIterator($array);
        $recursive = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
        $aHitList = array();
        foreach ($recursive as $key => $value) {
            if ($key === $needle) {
                array_push($aHitList, $value);
            }
        }
        return $aHitList;
    }

    $id = $_GET["id"];
    $link = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/id/'.$id.'/inventory/json/730/2');
    $link = json_decode($link, true);

    $name = recursiveFind($link, "market_hash_name");
    $csv = implode('<br />', array_values($name));

    echo '<b>Total: </b>';
    echo count($name);
    echo '<br />';

    #echo '<a href="http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/'.$csv.'" />';
    echo $csv;
   # echo '</a>';
?>
```

Example output:

> Total: 9
>   Glock-18 | Water Elemental (Field-Tested)
>   P250 | Supernova (Factory New)
>   StatTrak™ AK-47 | Elite Build (Field-Tested)
>   AWP | Worm God (Field-Tested)
>   M4A4 | Urban DDPAT (Field-Tested)
>   UMP-45 | Urban DDPAT (Field-Tested)
>   MAC-10 | Urban DDPAT (Field-Tested)
>   Desert Eagle | Urban DDPAT (Field-Tested)
>   Tec-9 | Urban DDPAT (Field-Tested)

And I want to add to each element a href link which starts "http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/**HERE EACH ELEMENT OF JSON**

How can I do it?

Comment: edit your question with the response json

Comment: @Viral json response: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=cQdsmZXp

Comment: Instead of using `implode`, use a for loop and add the link there.

Comment: how can i do it? im beginner, i dont know loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the following:

```
  // ...
 $name = recursiveFind($link, "market_hash_name");
 foreach($item in $name){
     echo $item;
     echo '<a href="http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/' . urlencode($item) . '" />';
     echo "<br/>";
 }
 echo '<b>Total: </b>';
 echo count($name);
 echo '<br />';
```